# Select values from the same row again with one query

Tags: php, mysql, select

I got a table with students, days and times. Some come every a week, some in even weeks, some in odd weeks. My table looks like:

[example of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VqND.png)

I need to build a query which checks which person to expect in the current week. I got code to determine the weeknumber, so i see if it is an odd or even week. But students with two times on the same day will only be shown once?

My query looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Student 
WHERE
    day1='$weekdag' 
    AND(week1='all' OR week1='even') 
    OR day2='$weekdag' AND (week2='all' OR week2='odd') 
ORDER BY time1, time2 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: normalize your db structure.

Comment: I would recommend you change the DB structure first. Use multiple tables

Comment: yes, you need two tables - one for the students themselves, and another one to describe attendance patterns (with a foreign key back to the student of course). Anytime you find yourself creating the same kind of column multiple times (e.g. week1, week2, that kind of thing), then it's usually time to think again about your structure. If you don't know much about "database normalisation" or concepts such as "1-to-many relationships", now would be a good time to learn!

Comment: A good reason to rationalise this particular structure would be, for example, if you decide to change to a 3-weekly pattern. In your current case, you have to re-design the table and all the queries which go with it in order to allow that. But if you have a separate attendance pattern table, which has one attendance pattern per row, then changing the timetable would be simply a case of adding some more rows. Nothing would need to change in the data structure.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I hoped for a simple answer but understand i have to change the database structure and build relationsships between tables.